# Using PCRE on ILE

Tags: regex, ibm-midrange, aix

I am trying to use the [pcre library](http://pcre.org/) (from AIX) on IBM iseries.
It should be possible using [PASE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzalf/rzalfintro.htm).

I installed the pcre library with the rpm provided by [yips](http://wsip-174-79-32-155.ph.ph.cox.net/wiki/index.php/PASE/OpenSourceBinaries).
I tried to use it in c ile source, but i couldn't achieve it.
Exemples : [yips](http://wsip-174-79-32-155.ph.ph.cox.net/wiki/index.php/PASE/RPG-2-PASE), [ibm](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/topic/rzalf/rzalfileprogcallsexamp.htm), [ibm redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg245970.html)

I can't find the way to do it.
Here is what i have done so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <qp2shell2.h>
#include <qp2user.h>
#define JOB_CCSID 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc;
    QP2_ptr64_t id;
    void *getpid_pase;
    const QP2_arg_type_t signature[] = { QP2_ARG_END };
    QP2_word_t result;

    /*
     * Call QP2SHELL2 to run the OS/400 PASE program
     * /usr/lib/start32, which starts OS/400 PASE in
     * 32-bit mode (and leaves it active on return)
     */
    QP2SHELL2("/usr/lib/start32");

    /*
     * Qp2dlopen opens the global name space (rather than
     * loading a new shared executable) when the first
     * argument is a null pointer.  Qp2dlsym locates the
     * function descriptor for the OS/400 PASE getpid
     * subroutine (exported by shared library libc.a)
     */

    id = Qp2dlopen("/usr/lib/libpcre.a", QP2_RTLD_NOW, JOB_CCSID);
    getpid_pase = Qp2dlsym(id, "pcrecpp::RE", JOB_CCSID, NULL);
    //id = Qp2dlopen(NULL, QP2_RTLD_NOW, JOB_CCSID);
    //getpid_pase = Qp2dlsym(id, "getpid", JOB_CCSID, NULL);

    /*
     * Call Qp2CallPase to run the OS/400 PASE getpid
     * function, and print the result.  Use Qp2errnop
     * to find and print the OS/400 PASE errno if the
     * function result was -1
     */
    rc = Qp2CallPase(getpid_pase,
                         NULL,        // no argument list
                         signature,
                         QP2_RESULT_WORD,
                         &result);
    printf("OS/400 PASE getpid() = %i\n", result);
    if (result == -1)
        printf("OS/400 errno = %i\n", *Qp2errnop());

    /*
     *  Close the Qp2dlopen instance, and then call
     *  Qp2EndPase to end OS/400 PASE in this job
     */
    Qp2dlclose(id);
    Qp2EndPase();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I tried the same and I could compile [pcre](http://pcre.org) to ILE using CRTCMOD.

In the zip-file of pcre you can find a file named NON_AUTOTOOLS_BUILD (if I remember the name correctly) with with all information needed to compile it.

In fact you only need to:

- edit config.h to match your environment (available functions like memmove, features like pthreads, EBCDIC support and NewLine=37 (x'25') )
- compile dftables.c using CRTBNDC DEFINE(HAVE_CONFIG_H) ...
- CALL DFTABLES to generate the character tables for EBCDIC (this step was a bit tricky, because it couldn't open the IFS-File for output. so I put the output in a source member and used CPYTOSTMF to get it in the IFS)
- compile the all the .c files unsing CRTCMOD DEFINE(HAVE_CONFIG_H) ...
- create a *SRVPGM from the modules
- write the Prototypes for RPG

It works like a charm, except for a little problem with CCSIDs. I generated the chartables for CCSID 1141, but for some reason PCRE expects input to be CCSID 37.

Also note that, if you write the prototypes in RPG, *pcre_free* is special. This function is not implemented in PCRE (you could write your own and plug it in if you want) and defaults to *free*. Your prototype should look like

```
Dpcre_free        PR                 EXTPROC('free')
D                                 *  value
```

<sup>*white spaces not accurate</sup>

Hope that helps